# coded ui the controls become blocked (hidden) after new page loads

Tags: coded-ui-tests

The controls in the page become blocked (hidden) after the new page loads. Error message :

Test method GUIAutomation.CodedUITest1.CodedUITestMethod1 threw exception: 
 Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.FailedToPerformActionOnHiddenControlException: Cannot perform 'Click' on the hidden control.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of this issue is: coded UI store the previous parameters of the window. When appeared the new window. Coded UI must have new search criteria for this new window. If the window have the same of search criteria. You must create the new instance of the window in coded UI.

Example:

```
SystemMessagePage message = new SystemMessagePage();
message.CloseExistMessage();   \\Close system message
```

If appeared the new system message window, we can't close this window by call of the method `message.CloseExistMessage();`.

To close a new system message window we must create a new instance of the window and repeat the previous code.

```
SystemMessagePage message = new SystemMessagePage();
message.CloseExistMessage();   \\Close system message
```